# nginx: remove subdirectory from url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

This web application I have always used to be in a directory `/foo`, so, I could access `http://example,com/foo`. But now they have changed that directory to `/foo/public` and I have to go to `https://example.com/foo/public`.

Because of boring reasons, the best way for me is to eliminate the extra subdirectory `public` from the url without moving files to a separate location. In nginx, how do I do this?

I tried a bunch of stuff including:

```
location /foo {
    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/mysite/foo/public;
}
```

But for some reason I'm either getting a 403 or a 404 saying that the directory `/var/www/example.com/htdocs/mysite/foo/public/foo/index.php` cannot be found.

***edit***

The relevant part of the config file now looks like this:

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}

location / {
    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/mysite;
}

location /foo/ {
    alias /var/www/example.com/htdocs/mysite/foo/public/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =403;
    fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass                    webmail;
    fastcgi_index                   index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    include                         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
}
```

It looks like there is now a problem with the PHP files inside of the /foo/ dir not working, and giving me a 403 error (or whatever I set the error code in the `try_files` line to). For example, there should be an `edit.php` file which returns error 403 when I try to open it. But, there is also an example.js file, and when I try to open that, it works.

Comment: You got an error because the location is always /foo. You must go to example.com/foo

Answer (score 0):

`root` basically prepends the specified path before the requested location, indcluding the part matched. This is why with `/foo` you end up in the `foo/public/foo` directory, which doesn't exist, hence the error. If you want to replace the matched location with a path, you should use `alias` instead.

Just changing `root` to `alias` should hopefully work for your case.

Source: [alias](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), [root](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

Comment: It doesn't. It just acts like nothing is there (in the old directory there is a file telling me that the path has changed to the public dir. I'm getting that file. To be sure I also tried to set a wrongful path and in that case I'm getting the 404 and the warning about a non-existent directory in the error log.

Comment: Thanks for helping btw. If I try to open `example.com/public` it tries to open `mysite/foo/public/public` so I'm stumped. Maybe it's a problem with php files only?

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to both your `location` and your `alias` parameters.

Comment: Yeah I did.. same issue.

Comment: Ok so the issue has to be with php files because in my nginx conf there is also a `location ~ .php$` block with a try_files line that includes `=403`, and I changed that to `=405`, and this causes me to get a 405 error.

Comment: Wait, why are you opening `example.com/public`? Didn't you want to access `example.com/foo`?

Comment: derp, sorry, that is a typo. But, I think that the alias directive actually worked and that this issue is limited now to just the php files. Do I need to copy the `location ~ .php$` block so it can handle this aliased directory?

Comment: I can't really help you with that without seeing your whole config, but it seems you now have an issue where the .php files aren't processed, meaning nginx would send back the raw PHP code, which the block you found is preventing for obvious reasons. You need to make sure you pass them through something like fastcgi so that they are properly rendered.